# Execute all cursors of a postgres function via c# Ado.net

Tags: c#, postgresql, plpgsql, npgsql

I have created a function postgres which returns 2 resultsets from different tables using refcursors. Now I want to call this function from C# but I can only call one cursor at a time by hardcoding the cursor name which is not ideal at all.  Is it possible to loop through the multiple cursors and execute them using C# ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multipleresultset()
RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
ref1 refcursor := 'cursor1';
ref2 refcursor := 'cursor2';
BEGIN open ref1 FOR SELECT * FROM table1;
RETURN NEXT ref1;

open ref2 FOR SELECT * FROM table2;
RETURN NEXT ref2;
--RETURN;END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

```
public DataTable GetMultipleResults()
{
    string connection = GetConnectionString("conn");
    NpgsqlConnection npgsqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connection);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        npgsqlConnection.Open();
        NpgsqlTransaction tran = npgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
        string query = "multipleresultset";
        NpgsqlCommand npgsqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, npgsqlConnection);
        npgsqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        npgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        npgsqlCommand.CommandText = "fetch all in \"cursor1\"";
        npgsqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    
        NpgsqlDataAdapter npgsqlDataAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(npgsqlCommand);
        npgsqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    
        tran.Commit();                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        npgsqlConnection.Close();
    }
    
    return dataTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like this inside Npgsql is tracked by https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1785 (not currently planned).

But it should be trivial to write an extension method that does this (some options are linked to from that issue).. Basically you'd read the cursor names coming back from the method, and then execute another roundtrip to get all the data from them. Issue #1785 is basically about doing that inside Npgsql, but it wouldn't have any advantage over doing it yourself (except for less code of course).

Finally, consider if you really need a stored function which returns multiple resultsets.. If you split it into two functions, each returning a single resultset, it's easier and more efficient (less roundtrips) to simply batch two calls together together. Or just batch the queries themselves, without functions at all. I'm saying this because people coming from other databases are sometimes in the habit of creating stored functions where none are necessarily needed.